# Problem with setup specific permissions for folders/files via ACL rights under Debial Linux 9.5

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, debian-stretch

please I want to ask you about setting specific permissions for files and folders via ACL rights under Linux. I have got problem with setup permissions for files. Folders works correctly.

I have got folder:

```
/test (with permissions -> chmod 777 /test)
```

Next setup was:

```
    setfacl -d -m u::rwx /test  
    setfacl -d -m g::rwx /test  
    setfacl -d -m o::rwx /test

    **result:**  
    file: test  
    owner: root   
    group: root    
    user::rwx   
    group::rwx  
    other::rwx
    
    default:user::rwx
    default:group::rwx
    default:other::rwx
```

**Now, when I create folder all is ok:**

```
mkdir data  
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 root root 4096 May 18 13:29 data
```

**But when I create any file, I have got file only with rw-,rw-,rw-**

```
touch data.txt 
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    0 May 18 13:30 data.txt
```

Could you please tell me what I doing wrong ? I need to create new files with rwx,rwx,rwx

Thank you very much.